# How to programmatically connect to wifi in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, wifi

I've been searching on this for quite some time, and have found lots of solutions that ultimately use the Android GUI to prompt the end-user for connection/confirmation. We would like to present a user with a form and directly connect to the specified network.  I understand from a security perspective why this is necessary, but in our case, it is a system app going on a fully managed Android device.  It is not intended for general use in the Play store.  We are using Xamarin, but I can adapt any Java/Kotlin code.

The closest I've found thus far is the following (using C#):

```
        public void ConnectToWifi(string ssid, string password = "") {
            var wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder().SetSsid(ssid);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                wifiNetworkSpecifier.SetWpa2Passphrase(password);
                    
            var networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder().AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi)?
                .SetNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier.Build())?.Build();

            if (networkRequest is null)
                return;

            var theNetworkCallback = new TheNetworkCallback();
            var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager?)MainActivity.Current.ApplicationContext?
                .GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            connectivityManager?.RequestNetwork(networkRequest, theNetworkCallback);
        }
```

It sorta works, but does prompt the end-user, and my understanding, this approach is deprecated and doesn't work well in newer versions of Android.  We're hoping for a solution that works in Android 11.

I'm even fine if there's a solution to write directly to wifi files on the OS.  I've seen various solutions to manually populate entries via ADB, but I'm having a tough time adapting that to Xamarin/Java (can't seem to access the /data/misc/wifi directories).  Again, this is intended for use exclusively on our own managed devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post about this topic here: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2020/11/android-11-wifi.html

Android Network API is not the greatest thing to work with as there are pitfals depending on the API level the code runs on.

From Android 10 and up a lot of the Network stuff has been restricted for "privacy" reasons, so you cannot work around not asking the user for input, unless the device is rooted or your App is set up as Device Admin.

For Android 11, there is a new API to present a system dialog and allow the user to save and connect to a network. This will look something like:
[image: screenshot of system dialog]

You can launch this through an Intent called `android.settings.WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS`:

```
var intent = new Intent(
    "android.settings.WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS");
var bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.PutParcelableArrayList(
    "android.provider.extra.WIFI_NETWORK_LIST",
    new List<IParcelable>
    {
        new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
            .SetSsid(ssid)
            .SetWpa2Passphrase(password)
            .Build()
    });

intent.PutExtras(bundle);

StartActivityForResult(intent, AddWifiSettingsRequestCode);
```

You can then get the result in your Activity overriding `OnActivityResult` and fetching the result like so:

```
if (requestCode == AddWifiSettingsRequestCode)
{
    if (data != null && data.HasExtra(
        "android.provider.extra.WIFI_NETWORK_RESULT_LIST"))
    {
        var extras =
            data.GetIntegerArrayListExtra(
                "android.provider.extra.WIFI_NETWORK_RESULT_LIST")
                ?.Select(i => i.IntValue()).ToArray() ?? new int[0];

        if (extras.Length > 0)
        {
            var ok = extras
                .Select(GetResultFromCode)
                .All(r => r == Result.Ok);
            // if ok is true, BINGO!
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a repository here with the full sample: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Android11WiFi

From using this in the wild, I've found that this API does not work nicely with some OEMs such as OnePlus and Huawei. Some of these either restrict or the System Settings App simply crashes due to a misconfiguration on their part. For those I fall back to the API's introduced in Android 10.